# Password protect uv4l-server control panel

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, raspbian-stretch

I am not one to sit back and let others solve my problem, but after days of working on this, I can't make it work. I want to link my web page to my camera's and I can do it-even can separate out ports as to have all 3 unique, but those so inclined will have access to control panel and camera settings. Documentation that I am following does not get me to password protecting my camera settings. Please, please help if you can. This page and all the links are what I have been trying to make work. https://www.linux-projects.org/documentation/uv4l-server/

Comment: Seems like this is a question about building a website that doesn't actually have anything to do with Raspberry Pi. This may not be the best site to get an answer for that.

Comment: *"Documentation that I am following does not get me to password protecting my camera settings."* -> This is something that you need to implement yourself, but general web programming is off-topic here.